# Does Web have effects outside of the creatures caught in it?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Are there any lingering effects from web spell? We had an encounter with 4 creatures, 2 of them caught in the web. After we killed the 2 caught in the web, one of us went for a melee attack on one of the other foes and our DM said “you're stepping over the web on the floor giving disadvantage.” Should Web's effects have continued after the creatures it caught had died?

Comment: Who cast the spell? Were they still maintaining concentration on it when you attempted to move into/through it? Was it attached to vertical supports (like walls, ceiling), or was it the "five-foot pile of goo on the ground" variety? Am I reading correctly that the web caught two foes in it and the other two foes were on the opposite side from your party?

Comment: The foes were all in one big room, and the web was on the ground. I did not end the spell,so i guess my ally stepped in the goo while advancing to the other two enemies

Comment: did the player who stepped in attempt a DEX save?

Comment: No, dm said he has disadvantage on the attack. We all missed that one, thx

Answer (score 6):

The rules as written for web seem pretty straightforward. There are two main points:

First, the spell requires concentration. As such, the caster can choose to end it at any time, no action required. If the caster chooses to maintain concentration, the spell can **last for up to an hour**.

Secondly, the web would affect creatures entering them. To quote, emphasis mine:

> Each creature that starts its turn in the webs or that **enters them during its turn** must make a dexterity saving throw. On a failed save, the creature is restrained...

If you want to go for maximum adherence, the web should technically have restrained the player (on a failed save) which carries additional penalties. For reference,

> - The creature's speed becomes 0, and it cannot benefit from bonuses to its speed.
> - Attacks against the creature have advantage, and the creature's attacks have disadvantage.
> - The creature has disadvantage on Dexterity saving throws.

Comment: Also, from spell's description:
 The webs are difficult terrain and lightly obscure their area.

Comment: "should have restrained the player" only applies if the player failed the save, which we don't know.

Comment: Good point. I had assumed a failed save, given the disadvantage. Post edited.